# QML dictionary (jsobject, var) sub-properties notify

Tags: qt, binding, qml, notify

Is it possible to raise notify-method of a `var`/`variant`/`object`/ (etc.) variables automatically during updating?

Suppose I have:

```
property var objects: {'obj1': 'unnamed', 'obj2': 'unnamed'}
```

Next I have binding in, for example, text:

```
Text {
    text: objects.obj1

    onTextChanged: objects.obj1 = text
}
```

In `onTextChanged` I want to raise a notify signal of `objects` variable to update it everywhere.

Comment: You should have a signal which you emit each time you change the JS object property value. And make sure it is never changed otherwise. You might consider using an accessor function which does that. Otherwise it will not work, you need `QObject` derived class for signals and therefore value change notifications to work.

Comment: @ddriver how can I implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, if I am not mistaken, QML generates a `onObjectsChanged` signal handler for `objects` but it is not emitted when you change `objects` internally, and due to QML brilliant design, you cannot emit `objectsChanged()` manually, it is expected to automatically emit, except that it doesn't. It only emits when the property is reassigned to another object.

You cannot create a signal for the JS object, since that requires a `QObject` derived class to get signals and therefore notifications and bindings.

You can force to emit `objectsChanged()` by reassigning the `objects` property a new object with the new value for obj1 and the old value of obj2, this will force the second text element to update and show the new value. It is not exactly elegant, but if you really need to use the JS object, it is a valid solution. Otherwise you will have to use a `QtObject` element and QML properties for `obj1/2`

```
property var objects: {'obj1': 'unnamed', 'obj2': 'unnamed'}

Column {
    spacing: 30

    TextEdit {
        text: objects.obj1
        onTextChanged: {
            objects = {'obj1': text, 'obj2': objects.obj2}
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: objects.obj1
    }
}
```

Another possible solution would be to simply not rely on notifications from `objects` and use a proxy property as a controller for it.

```
property var objects: {'obj1': 'unnamed', 'obj2': 'unnamed'}    
property string obj1: objects.obj1
onObj1Changed: objects.obj1 = obj1
```

This way you don't use `objects` at all, except for storing data into it, use the `obj1` property instead, and every time it is changed it will write the changed into `objects` without reassigning the entire objects as in the first solution.

But unless you really need the JS objects, I'd recommend scrapping it and using a more QML friendly data representation..